# Why are the site icons different sizes when you look at "All Sites"?

Tags: discussion, design

I found this site just moments ago and this question is eating away at me. I have compared all their stats, vistis per day, questions, answers, all that good stuff. I made this account just to have this question answered.

Can anyone fill me in on why they are different sizes? I don't even know why this is bugging me so much..[image: All the different sizes don't seem to mean anything regarding their stats]